# Cannot plot 2d array using imshow in matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I have tried several options to plot through `imshow`, but up to now I have not solved the error:

```
plt.imshow(data)
TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

I read a file with 6 columns, and I organise my data in the array

```
results = []
for line in open(filename,'r'):
    for word in line.split():
        results.append(word)

results = np.reshape(results,(length,6))
results = np.asarray(results, dtype=np.longdouble)
```

Now I want to take a column of such array and plot it using `imshow`. To do it I first compute

```
data = np.reshape(results[:,4],(20,20))
```

but now if I do `plt.imshow(data)` it returns the error `TypeError: Image data can not convert to float`. I don't understant what is going on here, since I have the correct 2d array through reshape, and `data` has the correct dimensions:

```
np.shape(data)
(20, 20)
```

Comment: Show ```data.dtype```.

Comment: It says `data type not understood`. I don't understand this...

Comment: You tried ```float``` instead of ```np.longdouble```?

Comment: I just switched to `float64`. It still spits `data type not understood`, __but__
 I can see the plot now. It sound like a bug...

Comment: sounds like your data aren't in the format you think they are

Comment: *"It says `data type not understood`."* That probably means you typed `np.dtype(data)` rather than `data.dtype`. `data.dtype` is an attribute of your `np.ndarray` instance `data`, whereas `np.dtype()` is a function that constructs a new data type object. Show us what `data.dtype` is.

Comment: If I set `dtype=float64` then indeed `data.dtype` returns `float64`, but if I say to numpy `dtype=np.longdouble`, then, when I want to plot the matrix using numpy, __matplotlib__ returns `data type not understood`.

Answer (score 0):

In line 6, Did you mean `results = np.reshape(results.shape[0],(length,6))` 
Because results is an array and not an integer